# C# Foreach to change certain object properties?

Tags: c#, object, properties, foreach, controls

I have a panel with checkboxes and labels, I want to change all the checked states of the checkboxes when I click a button.

```
foreach (object x in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (x.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                x.Checked = false; // problem is here;
                // (CheckBox)x.Checked = false; // also didn't work
            }
        }
```

I'm certain it's something simple but couldn't find how to resolve the issue. I was able to write the same procedure in vb.net but don't want to use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
((CheckBox)x).Checked = false;
```

As you wrote it, the compiler understand

```
(CheckBox)(x.Checked) = false;
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to put parentheses around the entire casting operation:

```
((CheckBox)x).Checked = false;
```

Answer (score 6):

You could definitely clean up your code a bit (as well as resolve the issue with parenthesis):

```
foreach(var x in panel1.Controls)
{
    var checkbox = x as Checkbox;
    if(checkbox != null) checkbox.Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(Checkbox box in panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
  box.Checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

x is still an object so you need to cast the object to a checkbox

```
((Checkbox)x).Checked = false;
```